# Array rerendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have some component like this:

```
const Todos = (props) => {
  const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = useState(null);

  return
    <>
      {todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} />)}
      {selectedTodo && <Modal />}
    </>
}
```

Lets assume this is `<Todo />`

```
const Todo = (props) => {

  return <div>{props.name}</div>
}
```

Let's say the `selectedTodo` triggers showing a modal or something.

If I update the `selectedTodo` value, all the todos will be re-rendered again.  If I put a console.log in the `<Todo>` component, I can see that it renders each time the state changes which makes sense.  However, if I have a huge list of todos, wouldn't that affect performance?

Is there a way to have it so that each Todo isn't re-rendered when I update `selectedTodos`?

Comment: `Todo` wouldn't be re-rendered if they were pure. How is it defined?

Comment: updated.  just a simple component

Comment: check that then https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo tld: wrap your `Todo` in `React.memo()` before you export it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `React.memo`, you can think of your component as an expensive function which returns whose result (the view) you want to keep saved until the data (todos) is changed

```
const TodoList = React.memo(({ todos }) => {
    return (<>
        {todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} />)}
    </>)
})
```

then just use TodoList as normal

```
return (<>
    <TodoList todos={todos} />
    <div>{selectedTodo && <p>hi</p>}</div>
</>)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo